# wp_insert_link not working

Tags: categories, links, link-category

Im using this code to insert links into my blog:

```
        $linkdata = array(
             'link_name' => $title,
             'link_url' => $url,
             'link_catetory' => 3, // my cat id
             );

        $link_id = wp_insert_link( $linkdata );
```

Links are inserted, but not in the correct category, I missed something?

Comment: Set second parameter to true and see if it returns any WP errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess `link_catetory` should be `link_category`. :)